# Laptop wireless weirdness

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Lenovo laptop running Windows 7 which I use at work in the office and then also at home. In both environments I connect it to the wireless network. When I use it at home, it appears that the act of connecting my laptop to my home's WiFi causes the speed of that network to drop dramatically to the point where it is almost completely unusable (only the WiFi, wired users do not see the effect). The WiFi router needs to be rebooted and then everything is OK, until the next day when I bring the laptop home from the work network again.

What possible cause could there be for such behaviour? N.B. Rebooting the laptop doesn't seem to help, the WiFi router has to be rebooted.

Happy to provide more details, just don't know what details would be useful since at a loss to know what could cause this.

Comment: Have you tried [deleting the home wireless network](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=windows+7+delete+wireless+network) from the computer and re-creating it?

Comment: I have not, but I will try it now and report back whether it improves matters. It will now have to wait until Monday before I am next on the work WiFi network for full proof.

Comment: Tried that, no difference.

Comment: Does your work have an IT department? If so, and they are approachable, I'd ask them. If it is a work-supplied laptop and you work from home, then definitely ask them.

Comment: What speed is it connecting to the home network with? Is it possible that it's forcing the home network into a poorer connection mode (maybe even 802.11b) and things aren't recovering? Check whether your home router is still supporting B, if so try changing it to only G, GN, AGN, AC whichever is appropriate.